# Computing latitude longitude center point of a Polygon in PHP

Tags: php, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a set of points (stored as lat/lon) for a polygon, I want to compute the lat/lon center point of the polygon in PHP.

Basically to do the same thing as the getCenter() function in Google Maps [LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [centroid of the polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Locating_the_centroid) - which is pretty easy to compute.  If you are using latitude/longitude the matter is complicated by the fact the the polygon is actually on the surface of a sphere (ellipsoid).

As an aside, why not just look at the Google api javascript code?

Comment: Thanks, searching is much easier with the correct terminology. It's part of a PHP import script, so I would prefer to keep it in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find a lot of formulas with the google queries "[center of gravity polygon](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Ffr&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=center+of+gravity+polygon&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)" or "[polygon centroid](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=5KC&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=polygon+centroid&aq=f&aqi=g6g-m4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)"

The sample from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid