# Is there a way of selecting lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2 from Envelope(Poly) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, polygon, latitude-longitude, point, envelope

If I have a column called Poly of type polygon in MySQL and I want to get the NW corner and the NE corner and the SE corner and the SW corner, how would I do that?  From an Envelope() there should be lat1, lat2, lon1, and lon2 that form the four corners as follows lat1,lon1 is NW; lat1,lon2 is NE; lat2,lon2 is SE; and lat2,lon1 is SW.  When I try X(PointN(Envelope(Poly),1)) AS lat1 it always returns NULL.  Can this be done in MySQL?

```
SELECT
    X(PointN(Envelope(Poly),1)) AS lat1, X(PointN(Envelope(Poly),3)) AS lat2,
    Y(PointN(Envelope(Poly),1)) AS lon1, Y(PointN(Envelope(Poly),2)) AS lon2
FROM boundaries.mt_us_zip5_2013_boundaries_polys_bin
WHERE zip = '00601';
```

The query above returns:

```
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Here's what the Envelope looks like:

```
SELECT AsText(Envelope(Poly))
FROM boundaries.mt_us_zip5_2013_boundaries_polys_bin
WHERE zip = '00601';
```

This last query returns:

```
POLYGON((18.111929 -66.836366,18.250344 -66.836366,18.250344 -66.659293,18.111929 -66.659293,18.111929 -66.836366))
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.36, would upgrading to a new version of MySQL give me the functions I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PointN` is only defined on `LineString`, but luckily you can call `ExteriorRing` on the `Polygon` to get a `LineString`. In your example:

```
SELECT
    X(PointN(ExteriorRing(Envelope(Poly)),1)) AS lat1,
    X(PointN(ExteriorRing(Envelope(Poly)),3)) AS lat2,
    Y(PointN(ExteriorRing(Envelope(Poly)),1)) AS lon1, 
    Y(PointN(ExteriorRing(Envelope(Poly)),2)) AS lon2
FROM boundaries.mt_us_zip5_2013_boundaries_polys_bin
WHERE zip = '00601';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with MySQL if it has this built-in but my first thought was to first find in the center of the polygon, then compute the bearing at each point on the poly from the center.  A bearing of 0 would be north and a bearing of 90 deg would be east, thus north-east would be 45 deg.  Find the points closest to the 45 deg angles gives you the corners.

Center of the polygon is here: [Computing latitude longitude center point of a Polygon in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011012/computing-latitude-longitude-center-point-of-a-polygon-in-php)

Computing bearing from 2 lat/lon points: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I can do this in Java or PHP, the problem is I want to put the logic in a MySQL stored procedure to speed things up.